# Remove DOM text from variable with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, dom

I need to Remove this `First Name :` ONLY.
I have already assign it to a variable. how to remove only that from  DOM.

example:

```
First Name :<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="" maxlength="100" />

var label = document.getElementById(id)['previousSibling'].nodeValue;
```

now the `label` variable contains the value `First Name :` I need to remove this dynamically from the DOM.

Comment: Please show the HTML code

Comment: Why can't you just set it to blank? ('')

Comment: First Name :<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="" maxlength="100" /> This is the Html. I need to remove that part dynamically once loaded to the web browser. need to change only in DOM and some other tag there. not permanantly. this is for a chrome extension. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) method like

```
var node = document.getElementById('firstName')['previousSibling'],
    label = node.nodeValue;
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j7YCW/)

Comment: Thank you soooo much. this worked. :) :) once again thanku for the help given