# Access the DOM text and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, var

I need to assign this "Pasta" text to a variable. and then remove it from here. 
If the text was in front can use 'previousSibling' but in this case what to use?

```
<input type="radio" name="lunch" id= "lunch" value="pasta" /> Pasta
```

Thank you so much inadvance :)

Something similar to this

[Remove DOM text from variable with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784959/remove-dom-text-from-variable-with-jquery)

Comment: This link doesn't work

Comment: Wrap in a span and get the text node.

Answer (score 0):

... `nextSibling`?

```
var textNode = document.getElementById('lunch').nextSibling;
var text = textNode.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
textNode.parentNode.removeChild(textNode);
// do something with var text
```

Not rocket science :p

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="fld">Pasta</span>


var p = document.getElementById("fld").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("fld").innerHTML ='';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
var element =  $('#lunch')[0].nextSibling
var text = element.nodeValue;
element.remove();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6CDc/

It would be easier if your markup was wrapped in some container element, e.g.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="radio" name="lunch" id="lunch" value="pasta" /> Pasta
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var text = $('#container').text();
$('#container').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6CDc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap them in a span and get the text node.

```
$('span').text();// returns text.
```